# How to generate a list of directories that has names starting with "A" and ending with "O"?

Tags: unix, find

How do I use the `find` command to generate a list of directories whose names starts with "A" and ends with "O"?

Comment: What's wring with `find . -name 'A*O' -type d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

```
$ find . -type d -name "A*O"
```

The `-type d` option tells `find` to only output directory names, and the `-name "A*O"` option further restricts those names to those matching the pattern `A*O` (i.e. starting with `A` and ending with `O`). It does this in the current directory (`.`) and will recursively enter any directory therein and performs the same task.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I also want to find the directroy which starts with "A" and ends with "O" or "I"??

Comment: @RavinderReddyAnugu Use `"A*[OI]"` instead of `"A*O"`.

Comment: Thank you its working!!.Colud you tell how to find the directory which starts with either "A" or "B" or "C"??

Comment: @RavinderReddyAnugu `"[ABC]*"`, really, this is quite basic. It accepts the same type of [globbing patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Syntax) as most shells does.

Comment: Got it now !!...How to find the directroy by the length of its name(ex: directroy which having its name with only 3 chracaters)?

Comment: @RavinderReddyAnugu *Seriously*... `"..."` (three dots).

Comment: did you mean find . -type d "..." ?

Comment: @RavinderReddyAnugu I'm only talking about the name filtering. The whole command would be `find . -type d -name "..."`.

Comment: Hi Kusal its not working i need to find the driectories whose name length is 3 ?

Comment: @RavinderReddyAnugu That is because I gave you the wrong answer. Have a look at the Wikipedia link I gave you a few comments ago, and do some of your own thinking. It is very basic, and very easy.

Comment: yes i got it by using "???" but its searching recursively through sub directroies i just want to search in main directroy only...

Comment: @RavinderReddyAnugu Well, there are other flags to `find` you may use. See if your implementation of `find` supports `-maxdepth=1`. Personally, I would not use `find` at all, but something like `for d in ???; do test -d $d && echo $d; done`

Answer (score 0):

You can use
**Case Sensitive - find . -type d -name  "A*O" 2>/dev/null***
**Case Insensitive - find . -type d -iname  "AO" 2>/dev/null**
We can use -i to ignore the case.